# placing variables from list in sql string

Tags: php, mysql

I created a mySQL database called myauthors,within myauthors I created one table called table 1.Then I created 4 select boxes(please see code).After which I created some code and a sql query with while loop to fill in the output(print or echo).It worked fine and printed the contents of the table out onto the screen. But this is what I am trying to do.When a user clicks on one of the values in the select box,I want it to be placed in a variable,which will then be placed into the sql query line.I tried adding this to the code below

```
    $aa = "author" 
    $bb = "publisher"
    $cc = "year"
    $dd = "genre"
```

where everything in the " " were the names of the select boxes.
and this for the query

```
'"$aa"' AND publisher= '"$bb"' AND year = '"$cc"' AND genre ='"$dd"' " ";
```

but it didn't work.
Am I barking up the wrong tree and is there another way of doing this.
Many thanks Jim

```
  <!DOCTYPE HTML>
  <html>
  <body>


  <select name = "author"> 
  <option value="kendavies">ken davies</option>
  <option value="arthursmith">arthur smith</option>
  <option value="gillrafferty">gill rafferty</option>
  <option value="mollybrown">molly brown</option>
  <option value="gilbert riley">gilbert riley</option>
  <option value="colinwilson">colin wilson</option>
  <option value="jamesgreen">james green</option>
   <option value="arnoldlaing">arnold laing</option>
  <option value="cathyellis">cathy ellis</option>
  <option value="carolreed">carol reed</option>    

  </select>

 <select name = "publisher"> 
 <option value="yonkers">yonkers</option>
  <option value="blueparrot">blue parrot</option>
  <option value="zoot">zoot</option>   

  </select>
    <select name = "year"> 
  <option value="2003">2003</option>
  <option value="2004">2004</option>
  <option value="2005">2005</option>
  <option value="2006">2006</option>
  <option value="2007">2007</option>
  <option value="2008">2008</option>

  </select>

   <select name = "genre"> 
   <option value="adventure">adventure</option>
   <option value="thriller">thriller</option>
  <option value="crime">crime</option>
  <option value="biography">biography</option>
   <option value="romance">romance</option>     

  </select>

      </body>
 </html>       
<?php             
 mysql_connect ("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
 mysql_select_db ("myauthors") or die(mysql_error());  
 $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM `table 1`"; 
 $rs = mysql_query($strSQL);    



while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs) ) {  

print $row ['ID']."<br/>";             
print $row ['author']."<br/>";   
print $row ['booktitle']."<br/>";
print $row ['publisher']."<br/>";
print $row ['yearpublished']."<br/>";
 print $row ['genre']."<br/>";
print $row ['copiessold']."<br/>";

 }
   mysql_close();
    ?> 
  </body>  
  </html>
```

I Have added the variables and the new sql line to the code but it is still not working here is what the code looks like now.

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
  <html>
  <body>


  <select name = "author"> 
  <option value="kendavies">ken davies</option>
   <option value="arthursmith">arthur smith</option>
  <option value="gillrafferty">gill rafferty</option>
  <option value="mollybrown">molly brown</option>
  <option value="gilbert riley">gilbert riley</option>
   <option value="colinwilson">colin wilson</option>
    <option value="jamesgreen">james green</option>
   <option value="arnoldlaing">arnold laing</option>
  <option value="cathyellis">cathy ellis</option>
   <option value="carolreed">carol reed</option>    

  </select>

  <select name = "publisher"> 
  <option value="yonkers">yonkers</option>
   <option value="blueparrot">blue parrot</option>
  <option value="zoot">zoot</option>   

  </select>
    <select name = "year"> 
  <option value="2003">2003</option>
   <option value="2004">2004</option>
  <option value="2005">2005</option>
  <option value="2006">2006</option>
  <option value="2007">2007</option>
  <option value="2008">2008</option>

  </select>

   <select name = "genre"> 
  <option value="adventure">adventure</option>
   <option value="thriller">thriller</option>
  <option value="crime">crime</option>
  <option value="biography">biography</option>
  <option value="romance">romance</option>     

  </select>
  $aa = "author" 
  $bb = "publisher"
  $cc = "year"
  $dd = "genre" 
      </body>  
</html>       
<?php    

  $aa = "author"; 
  $bb = "publisher";
  $cc = "year";
  $dd = "genre";     
 mysql_connect ("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
 mysql_select_db ("myauthors") or die(mysql_error());  
  $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM `table 1`WHERE author = '$aa' AND publisher = '$bb'       AND  year = '$cc' AND genre ='$dd'  ";  
  $rs = mysql_query($strSQL);    



  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs) ) {  

 print $row ['ID']."<br/>";             
 print $row ['author']."<br/>";   
  print $row ['booktitle']."<br/>";
 print $row ['publisher']."<br/>";
 print $row ['yearpublished']."<br/>";
 print $row ['genre']."<br/>";
 print $row ['copiessold']."<br/>";


  }
 mysql_close();
 ?> 
 </body>  
 </html>
```

Comment: I don't understand your question, do you want to do insert query?

Comment: I suspect the problem is the double quotes.  Did you try:  `'$aa' AND publisher= '$bb' AND year = '$cc' AND genre ='$dd'"`?

Comment: HI Gordon,Thanks for the reply.I have tried that but doesn't workI was wondering if I have to put something like $ variable = option value of "name.Similar to what you find in vb.net.Rather than just the name of the list box(select box).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
"'$aa' AND publisher= '$bb' AND year = '$cc' AND genre = '$dd'";
```

Comment: Hi Sagar,thanks for the reply.It didn't weork and I was thinking perhaps I have to refer specifically to the element in the array.i.e something like $var = options(option being something in the list)I will keep pluggin away :)

Comment: Based on what you describe, this answer should work.  Keep in mind that the entire statement would be in double quotes, like "UPDATE table set author='$aa', publisher='$pp', year='$cc', genre='$dd' WHERE condition".  If this isn't what you are trying to do, please provide more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Concat with dots `.`

```
'".$aa."' AND publisher= '".$bb."' AND year = '".$cc."' AND genre ='".$dd."' ";
```

Comment: Hi Parag Many Thanks for your reply,I copy and pasted your line of code and it came up with this..Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"' in C:\xampp\htdocs\moon\newmoon2.php on line 59...I have been fiddling about with the commas and stuff  but to know avail.I am thinking if the problem lies with the original variables and the way I stored them.

Comment: I guess there is an extra `"` in the statement. Check edit now and coy paste.